# wordpress too many redirects home page

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've changed PERMALINKS from Plain to Postname and when I load homepage i see "too many redirects" mistake.

Other pages work fine.

I've tried deactivating all plugins, nothing helps.

Maybe the problem is that my website name is in russian:
собеседование-на-английском.рф
(which is "xn-----6kcbbbhncjad2bgpqovhddheq6cds.xn--p1ai").

any suggestions?

Comment: change the theme please. Just rename active theme folder name

Comment: thanx, tried, the same thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is due to wrong Url format

Open Wp-config.php file in your root directory and add

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Replace example .com with your site url an If you still can not access your site, then try to add your domain with www prefix.

Comment: works! changed to define('WP_HOME','http://xn-----6kcbbbhncjad2bgpqovhddheq6cds.xn--p1ai');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://xn-----6kcbbbhncjad2bgpqovhddheq6cds.xn--p1ai');

Comment: I am having the exact same problem but that doesn’t fix it